# Change Spark day timestamp from name to number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, dayofweek

I'm trying to get the day of the week in int format from it saying Mon, Tues, Wed, etc.

I'm using this code right now:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
df_ex1 = df.withColumn("day", date_format('Timestamp', 'E'))
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+----+----+----+-----+------------+-----------------+--------------+----+-----+---+
|Timestamp          |Open|High|Low |Close|Volume_(BTC)|Volume_(Currency)|Weighted_Price|Year|Month|day|
+-------------------+----+----+----+-----+------------+-----------------+--------------+----+-----+---+
|2011-12-31 09:52:00|4.39|4.39|4.39|4.39 |0.45558086  |2.0              |4.39          |2011|12   |Sat|
|2011-12-31 09:53:00|NaN |NaN |NaN |NaN  |NaN         |NaN              |NaN           |2011|12   |Sat|
|2011-12-31 09:54:00|NaN |NaN |NaN |NaN  |NaN         |NaN              |NaN           |2011|12   |Sat|
|2011-12-31 09:55:00|NaN |NaN |NaN |NaN  |NaN         |NaN              |NaN           |2011|12   |Sat|
|2011-12-31 09:56:00|NaN |NaN |NaN |NaN  |NaN         |NaN              |NaN           |2011|12   |Sat|
+-------------------+----+----+----+-----+------------+-----------------+--------------+----+-----+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: do you want to fetch the day of the week from the timestamp? you can use [`dayofweek`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek.html#pyspark-sql-functions-dayofweek) function. [more pyspark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html#functions)

Comment: I need dayofweek with a number instead of letters.   

# Write your code to add a 'Weekday' column to the DataFrame here: 
# Note that the weekday can be represented as an integer, i.e. Sunday --> 1, Saturday --> 7.    

That's the assignment and I am plain doff at spark coding lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Spark native ways: [`dayofweek`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek) and [`weekday`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#weekday) (the latter - only SQL).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2022-08-01', 'Mon'),
     ('2022-08-02', 'Tue'),
     ('2022-08-03', 'Wed'),
     ('2022-08-04', 'Thu'),
     ('2022-08-05', 'Fri'),
     ('2022-08-06', 'Sat'),
     ('2022-08-07', 'Sun')],
    ['Timestamp', 'day'])

df = df.withColumn('day_number_1', F.dayofweek('Timestamp'))
df = df.withColumn('day_number_2', F.expr("weekday(Timestamp)"))

df.show()
# +----------+---+------------+------------+
# | Timestamp|day|day_number_1|day_number_2|
# +----------+---+------------+------------+
# |2022-08-01|Mon|           2|           0|
# |2022-08-02|Tue|           3|           1|
# |2022-08-03|Wed|           4|           2|
# |2022-08-04|Thu|           5|           3|
# |2022-08-05|Fri|           6|           4|
# |2022-08-06|Sat|           7|           5|
# |2022-08-07|Sun|           1|           6|
# +----------+---+------------+------------+
```